# Ubuntu 14.04 VM kernel panics once every ~5-9 days on Hyper-V

Tags: 14.04, kernel, virtualization, nagios3, hyper-v

I have an x64 Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS virtual machine running the hardware monitoring and status software Nagios. The VM seems to be kernel panicking once every 5-9 days. I am unable to pin down the cause.

I am currently the only person that uses Nagios on this machine. When it kernel panics, it's not being used by anybody (and to my knowledge, not doing much else besides receiving monitoring updates from other computers). Additionally, the VM is only available on the local network, and I've regularly kept everything up-to-date using apt-get update and apt-get upgrade.

The link below shows two images showing the screen when the VM kernel panics. Every kernel panic seems to be a slight variation of one of these two images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CrDD.png

The VM runs on Hyper-V on a computer with Windows Server 2012 Standard installed. However, the server runs 6 other VMs without incident (including Ubuntu 12.04 and CentOS 6 VMs).

Is it possible that Hyper-V integration services or drivers are at fault? I keep seeing hv_storvsc and references to Hyper-V in the kernel panics and am wondering if the Hyper-V drivers in 14.04 are subpar or have known issues.

The VM has been in operation for about 1.5 years, but these problems have only started surfacing a few months ago, if I recall correctly.

**Additional information about the virtual machine:**

- 1 virtual processor assigned
- 1024MB RAM
- Hard drive on IDE Controller 0
- Virtual hard disk resides on the server's C:\ drive
- All integration services are enabled for the VM, including: operating system shutdown, time synchronization, data exchange, heartbeat, backup (volume snapshot)
- Replication is enabled to a server in the same rack with identical hardware

**Additional information about the host server that runs Hyper-V:**

- Powershell script runs every night that runs Windows Backup on all VMs to a local external hard drive
- Motherboard: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128577
- CPU: AMD A8-5600K quad-core 3.6GHz CPU
- RAM: 32GB (4x 8GB) CORSAIR Vengeance DDR3 1866
- All RAM has been tested thoroughly with memtest86+
- System has been stress tested with Prime95
- System has been in operation for about 2.5 years
- 2x 1TB HDs set up in RAID1 using the motherboard's onboard RAID controller
- Raid software has not given any indication of problems with the array

Any help would be appreciated. I've been Googling around for days and haven't come up with any reasonable theories. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I made this experience with some specific kernel version. Upgrading to newer kernel version or going back to older kernel version fixed it for me.

Comment: This is a vague answer.  It would be helpful to the person who asked if you could supply a short procedure on how to accomplish this.